# const_iterator vs iterator for std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, stdlist

Is there any major difference between `const_iterator` and `iterator` implementations for std::list except `operator*` and `operator->`. Below you can see my non-templated homework-style example to show the gist. As much as I understand the rest of the methods just copy each-other for these classes, such as CTOR, `operator==`, `operator!=`, `operator++`, `operator++(int)`, `operator--`, `operator--(int)`.

```
class iterator
{
private:
    Node* m_node;

public:
    iterator(Node* node)
        : m_node(node)
    {

    }

    int& operator*()
    {
        return m_node->value;
    }

    Node* operator->()
    {
        return m_node;
    }

 ....
}
```

Now const iterator implementation

```
class const_iterator
{
private:
    Node* m_node;

public:
    const_iterator(Node* node)
        : m_node(node)
    {

    }

    int operator*() const
    {
        return m_node->value;
    }

    const Node* operator->() const
    {
        return m_node;
    }
......
}
```

If this is the major difference, then we should handle the duplication too, right?

Comment: Is your iterator convertible to const_iterator?

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, I think it should be, but I have not written that. There should be `operator const_iterator` for `iterator`?

Comment: I have seen `iterator` derived from `const_iterator` in some implementations.

Comment: Yup, such as in Microsoft's impl! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few things described below, and the class is not "templetized" yet, but the approach is the same as what [one implementation](http://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/stl__list_8h-source.html) of the Standard Template Library is using.

- **Both iterators need a default constructor** - this provides a way to make a null iterator, which you can assign later
- **`const_iterator` must be constructible from `iterator`** - Add a constructor to `const_iterator` to accept "regular" iterator.

As far as code duplication is concerned, this is a fair observation indeed. However, most implementations fit on a single line, and return different types, so trying to share implementations across the two templates would make the code harder to read.

Comment: How does an implementation of `iterator` or `const_iterator` fit on a single line?

Comment: I think - "method" implementations is implied.

Comment: @Yakk I am talking about implementations of member functions and operators (see link to the source, and scroll down to "iterator" implementation).